# Will water flow into a tank connected to a hole in a pipe?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure

[image: Figure 1]

Consider water flowing through a pipe from a pump to an outlet at atmospheric pressure. The pipe has a hole in the bottom which initially connects to an empty tank.

1. The water fills the tank.
2. Once the tank is filled with water and steady state is reached, a dye is mixed in the water that is pumped in the pipe.

Will this dye be seen inside the tank? Assume that the pump and the outlet are far away from the hole.

Comment: $P_3 > P_2$. So, tracer should not enter the tank. Will that be correct?

Comment: Will the entry hole to the tank create a flow disturbance?

Comment: @SolarMike what is your thought if it does not? I am thinking, obviously there will be some flow disturbance near the hole. Maybe, that gets minimized if the velocity is slow enough.

Comment: When you say "tracers" are you talking about a dye or something like small plastic pellets?

Comment: @J.Ari I am talking about dye. The one which can track fluid flow without affecting the flow itself with hydrodynamic interactions.

Comment: "introduced in the pipe" diagram shows upstream.  could be done far enough downstream and... upstream far enough and it can be the same as what fills the tank initially.  There are many more variables at play, and varying results with them.

Comment: @Abel I have edited the question, does that clarify it for you?

Comment: still plenty of variables to play with including flow rate, pipe diameter, size of hole in box, and properties of the "dye" - for example if the dye is basically oil, and the flow slow enough, and the pipe diameter large enough, I could see it failing to enter the box.  A better approach might be to figure out the results you want and to design the system to meet requirements.  That or given an existing system, provide as thorough measurements as possible.

Answer (score 2):

There will be turbulent flow at the hole to the tank.  This will produce eddy currents in the tank, and there will be a slow exchange of fluid between the tank and the pipe.

Comment: Are you expecting a reynolds' number cutoff for the turbulent flow to happen?

Comment: @Brownian_Motion, no, it will be turbulent because it passses a hole.